# Getting Malformed Query error when hitting SOQL using Rest API

Tags: soql, rest-api, test-automation

I have a requirement to fetch query results of a SOQL query using REST API. Even after encoding the SOQL search I keep on getting Malformed Query error. I am so far unable to find a reason to it.

This is how I am constructing the endpoint :

```
    String sfdcEndPoint = "https://something--env.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/query/?q=";
    String Query = "select Id, Object__r.Contract_Terms__c,Object2__r.Free_Month_Period__c,Object3__r.CurrentContractStartDate__c, EndDate__c, Object4__r.Free_Month_End_Date__c, Object5__r.name, ProductId__r.ProductType__c, ProductId__r.Is_3rd_Party__c, Is_EPP__c, Charge_Frequency__c, PriceType__c, Perpetual__c, NetUnitPrice__c, billing_tcv__c, Billing_MRR__c from OrderLineItem__c where OrderId__c IN('"+orderId+"')order by ProductId__r.ProductType__c, Charge_Frequency__c";

    String sfdcQuery= sfdcEndPoint+URLEncoder.encode(Query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This is the query formed post encoding

```
 https://something--env.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/query/?q=select+id%2CEndDate__c%2C+Is_EPP__c%2C+Charge_Frequency__c%2C+PriceType__c%2C+Perpetual__c%2C+NetUnitPrice__c%2C+billing_tcv__c%2C+Billing_MRR__c+from+OrderLineItem__c+where+OrderId__c+IN%28%27a6R6C000000DLlxUAG%27%29+order+by+Charge_Frequency__c
```

I ran the query in dev console as well as workbench where I am seeing the proper result but not sure why I cannot get one using Rest API.

So far I have tried replacing "query" with "search" in endpoint. Tried to simply the query by removing cross object references but i continue getting 400 as response. Ran with both encoded and non encoded URL.

Response :

```
{"message":"A query string has to be specified","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}
```

Please feel free to guide me to a existing question/documentation that might help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be here   `OrderId__c IN('"+orderId+"')order` here you need to give space between **)** and **order** i.e `OrderId__c IN('"+orderId+"') order`
If the issue still persisted make sure that **orderId** values are comma-separated(If multiple values)

While encoding query use this format : /services/data/v52.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account you don't need to urlencode it.

Comment: Thanks Aniket, I updated this and still no luck. Also orderId will be having only single value. I replaced = with IN to check if it has something to do with this issue.

Comment: Hi Kovid, There is an issue with your query encoding. you have to write custom encoding logic for API query string. Refer to this document https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm